# Win10: change/disable pre-login picture

Tags: windows-10, login-screen

I have a Surface Pro 3 running Win 10 on the latest update. Since a recent update, on the first screen after the "Surface" loading one, the screen showing date/time just before you swipe up to enter your password, Windows has started showing random background photos that change every few days. I would like to turn this off.

I have tried all the usual methods suggested online:

- Settings / Lock Screen, then disable/change switches there
- Turn off Content Delivery Manager globally with a registry edit
- Delete the Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager* folders in AppData/Local.

No luck - the images keep coming and changing every few days. How do I turn this off?

Note: I'm not asking about the lock screen, but the screen with the clock and date that appears when you boot *before* you swipe up to get the lock screen.

Here's my control panel settings

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not asking about the lock screen, but the screen with the clock
> and date that appears when you boot before you swipe up to get the
> lock screen.

That is still the lock screen (only screen before you log on)

Settings, Personalization, Lock Screen:   Turn off Slide Show and / or Spotlight.  Check also Themes.

Be sure to disable fun facts and tips (Setting in Lock Screen) from windows and Cortana

News and Interests (Task Bar Settings) come after login.

I have Windows 10 on two laptops with these features turned off, and with Windows 10 fully up to date (updates in the last 7 days from the date of this post)

If the above does not work for you, then you may need to do a Windows 10 Repair Install  or greater Repair.

Comment: I don't think that is correct, unfortunately. I already have these settings off - I've added an image link above, where I tried to set the lock screen to a jpg that is just a single color.

This works for the screen _after_ I swipe up, on which I can enter my password, but not for the screen _before_ with the clock and date.

Comment: I also added a section about Fun Facts and tips. These are all the settings there are for lock screen. There is not much else

Comment: Check my screenshot - these are _already off_. And yet Windows still shows me photos first thing when I start up.

Comment: I have posted all the settings that affect this. I have not seen (5 years of Windows 10) anything else,

Comment: You may need to repair Windows 10 if nothing else works.

Comment: @Cranberry - The behavior you describe absolutely is Windows Spotlight.